# Australian Head of State

Tags: britain, monarchy, australia

Under the Australian Constitution, who will become Australia's Head of State if the British monarchy is suddenly dissolved or overthrown and Britain becomes a republic?

Comment: The *sovereignty of Parliament* means that only the Australian Parliament can decide that, and only by having the question put to it. Anything else is conjecture. If I had to bet, it would be that the Governor General would eventually be replaced by an elected President, but that on an interim basis Parliament would invest the incumbent would continuation of pre-existing authority.

Comment: How is this a history question?

Comment: This should go to politics.SE

Comment: @KillingTime It's on hold, so it's history now ;)

Answer (score 6):

Australia calls Elisabeth II "Her Majesty Elizabeth the Second, by the Grace of God, Queen of Australia and Her other Realms and Territories, Head of the Commonwealth." This formula does not mention that the Queen of Australia is also Queen of England. If the British ruling dynasty is overthrown in *one* of her realms, in theory that does not affect her standing in the other realms.

In practice England is not quite comparable to the other realms of the Queen.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25654)

Comment: @CGCampbell, I think it does. If the British ruling dynasty is overthrown in *one* of her realms, in theory that does not affect her standing in the other realms. In practice England is not quite comparable to the other realms of the Queen.

Comment: It might answer the question better if you put your comment in your answer